# What type of series expansion is this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I'd really appreciate it if you guys could tell me what type of series expansion method is going on here. I originally thought it was a geometric series since it's in the form $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^n x^{k}$$

but this doesn't look right since it then should be in the form:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{\infty} r^i = \dfrac{1}{1-r}$ is for infinitely many terms and with $|r| < 1$.

However, for finitely many terms, $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n r^i = \dfrac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}, r \neq 1$.
The formula for infinitely many terms can be derived from this generalized case when $n \to \infty$ and $|r| < 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Remember, $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$

Now notice that
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{-k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 5^k.$$
Also $\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{-k} = \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{k} $

After some algebraic tomfoolery, we get your last line.